# Is this this best way to change a table row into a form on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance

I have written the below jQuery to allow a row of a table to be changed into editable form on upon a link being clicked. The class of the row is passed into function.

```
function enableform(x) {

    $("." + x +" .disabled").prop("disabled", false);
    $(".icon-pencil").css("display", "none");
    $( "." + x +" input" ).removeClass("disabled");
    $( "." + x +" select" ).removeClass("disabled");
    $( "." + x +" td.dropdown" ).addClass("test");
    $( "." + x +" td" ).removeClass("dropdown");
    $("." + x +" .icon-ban").css("visibility", "visible");
    return false;
};

function disableform(x) {
    $( "." + x +" input" ).addClass("disabled");
    $( "." + x +" select" ).addClass("disabled");
    $( "." + x +" td.test" ).addClass("dropdown");
    $("." + x +" .disabled").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".icon-pencil").css("display", "block");
    $("." + x +" .icon-ban").css("visibility", "hidden");
    return false;
};
```

Basically the form is already there but with classes applied to make it look like static text, and the disabled property is used to make them not editable. When the button at the end of each row is clicked the corrosponding row is changed back into a form and the reverse when the cancel button is clicked. Basically i just want someone with more experience to tell me whether or not this is the best way to acheive this and if not, how can it be improved?

Comment: what about instead of creating individual elements you have an empty 'editable' row that you can replace a non-editable one with on click and then just set the correct values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems a bit tedious.  I would recommend creating CSS rules for both states and add / remove a class on the parent container of the row so you don't have to add multiple classes to multiple elements and tweak lots of css values.

ie

```
.parent_row input{ /* stuff for disabled inputs*/}
.parent_row input{ /* stuff for disabled selects*/}
.parent_row .icon-ban{ /* stuff for disabled .icon-ban*/}
.parent_row.enabled input{ /* stuff for enabled inputs*/}
.parent_row.enabled input{ /* stuff for enabled selects*/}
.parent_row.enabled .icon-ban{ /* stuff for enabled inputs*/}
```

then in your JS, toggle that class.

```
function enableform(x) {
var element = $("." + x); 
element.addClass("enabled");
element.prop("disabled", false);
return false;
};

function disableform(x) {
var element = $("." + x); 
element.removeClass("enabled"); 
element.prop("disabled", true);
return false;
};
```

Not really sure why you're returning `false` or why you're messing with a "disabled" attribute...would need to see more code there to comment on that so i left it in the code

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend adding classes (to hide/show, make editable, etc.) to the ROW instead of each element inside. So onClick you would have the button get what row it is in and then set a class on that row (something like "editable").

Where you used to have styling like this:

```
input.disabled{
  --styles go here--
}
select.disabled{
  --styles go here--
}
```

You would now have

```
tr.enabled input{
  --styles go here--
}
tr.enabled select{
  --styles go here--
}
```

Comment: I'm not showing/hiding elements apart from a couple of links, im chaning the appearance of form fields to make them not look like fields anymore and making them disabled so they can't be edited.

Comment: Right... so the appearance changing styles would go where it says "--styles go here--". This can include anything from showing/hiding to changing the borders, colors, font, etc.

Comment: Sorry, read your post wrong! makes sense now!

Answer (score 1):

Your code could use improvement.  Because of all the different jquery selects it looks very convoluted and difficult to read.  I simplified some of your code like this:

```
function enableform(x) {
    $("." + x +" .disabled").prop("disabled", false).removeClass("disabled");
    $( "." + x +" td.dropdown" ).addClass("test");
    $( "." + x +" td" ).removeClass("dropdown");
    $(".icon-pencil").hide();
    $("." + x +" .icon-ban").show();
    return false;
};

function disableform(x) {
    $( "." + x +" input select" ).addClass("disabled");
    $( "." + x +" td.test" ).addClass("dropdown");
    $("." + x +" .disabled").prop("disabled", true);
    $(".icon-pencil").css("display", "block");
    $("." + x +" .icon-ban").hide();
    return false;
};
```

Notice you can use multiple selector statements within one jquery command.  Then you can chain different functions to that same selection.

I noticed you are returning false since these are button presses and I am guessing you are putting onclick="dosomething()" in your html.  Instead of doing this bind a click function to the button:

```
$("#buttonID").click(function(){
    Do code here.  $(this) is the object of the currently clicked button if we need it.
})
```

I haven't tested my code but it should get you going in the right direction.